# Spell check is configured for English only

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm writing test cases in Polish, but spell check is obviously configured for English. Can I switch to other language or disable spell checking, so it won't mark most of my text?

I couldn't find any entry for this in settings nor any config in docker files.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic spell check is a browser/OS feature so Kiwi TCMS can't help you with that. For example as I type this answer I get every single word highlighted because my Linux desktop is configured for Bulgarian, not English.

Being a Django project Kiwi TCMS will try to translate the interface to the language detected by the browser. This affects display only, not input.

We do not have Polish translation so if this is something you would like to contribute to I will enable it in Crowdin (see documentation on how to contribute).

Comment: I have spell check disabled in browser, cannot even enable it in Kiwi (i.e. on stackoverflow it's working). In `/Kiwi/static/` is `codemirror-spell-checker` directory, and it has [his own page on github](https://github.com/sparksuite/codemirror-spell-checker) and it looks exactly the same in demo and in Kiwi. Removing dir is not resolving my issue. It has something to do with Kiwi or it's not relevant?

Comment: codemirror and codemirror-spell-checker are dependencies of SimpleMDE - this is the JavaScript library providing the markdown editor. If you mean to turn off this function inside the editor (e.g. test plan document) then you probably have to report an issue on GitHub. Not sure how to do that ATM.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style in the file patternfly_override.css and mount it in docker. You have 2 templates CSS, but in your write:

```
.CodeMirror .cm-spell-error:not(.cm-url):not(.cm-comment):not(.cm-tag):not(.cm-word) {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0) !important; }
```

This will remove the error highlighting. I did this for the Russian language in the Google Chrome browser, in other browsers the localization was determined well and there was no red highlight.